# Find largest value in index 0 of a nested list

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, nested

I have a nested list and I want to find the largest value stored in a specific index of the nested list.

For example: `data = [[12345678, 14, 1],[135763365, 12, 0],[1234, 9, 0]]`

I want to return the largest value stored in index 0 of the list `data`: `135763365`.

How can I return this? I don't want to brute force figure out the largest myself and return that value. I want to write a function that will return this value in a nested list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `list comprehension` and apply [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function over result.

```
max_number = max([item[0] for item in data])
```

Output

```
135763365
```

Another approach is to specify key in the `max` function.

```
max(data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))[0]
```

Comment: If multiple lists have the same value as an element. How would you print the duplications out?

Answer (score 0):

Using `max` and `lambda`:

```
>>> data = [[12345678, 14, 1],[135763365, 12, 0],[1234, 9, 0]]
>>> max(data, key=lambda x: x[0])[0]
135763365
```

Comment: If multiple lists have the same value as an element. How would you print the duplications out?